# How to fetch data from SQL table using button and replace the current table?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

My page already has a table filled using a select statement upon entering

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE isArchived = :zero ORDER BY addedAt DESC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":zero", 0);
    $stmt->execute();
?>
-------------------------------------------------------
    <tbody>
    <?php   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $id = md5($row['personId']);
    $lName = $row['lName'];
    $fName = $row['fName'];
    $mName = $row['mName'];
    $suffixName = $row['suffixName'];
    $gender = $row['gender'];

//and so on...
```

I want to show all archived people (just have to set isArchived from 0 to 1) from the press of a button, but I don't know how to repopulate the while loop (and in turn display the new selected data) without reloading the page, because each `td` has a script that allows inline update like

```
<td><div contenteditable="true" onBlur="updateValue(this, 'lName', '<?php echo $id;?>')" onClick="activate(this)"><?php echo $lName; ?></div></td>
```

I tried this but it doesnt work. It reaches the PHP echo but nothing happens otherwise.

```
$('#display-archived').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "selectunarchivedpeople.php",
        data: $('#table').serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(php_result) {
            console.log(php_result);
        }
    })
})
```

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE isArchived = :zero ORDER BY addedAt DESC";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":zero", 1);

if($stmt->execute()){
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $id = md5($row['personId']);
        $lName = $row['lName'];
        $fName = $row['fName'];
        $mName = $row['mName'];
        $suffixName = $row['suffixName'];
 //and so on...
    }
    echo "Yup";       
}
else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: Build an array of the query results, suggest selecting only what you want to return and then using `$returns = $stmt->fetch_all()` and then make a JSON String from `$results` as in `$returned = json_encode($results);` and then `echo $results;` That will return that JSON String to the JS code in `success function(data){` in the `data` variable. It will be a javscript object which you can process to build a new table

Comment: Alternatively, make the PHP build the new HTML table in a text variable. `echo`  that to the javascript and then simply replace the table with the new table with a simple bit of Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about the inline scripts, you should worry about the way your client-side and server-side communicates. Let's see the parts:

## Server to provide the information

You should have something of the like:

```
function getValues($archived = null) {
    $archivedCriteria = "";
    if (($archived === 1) || ($archived === 0)) {
        $achivedCriteria = " AND isArchived = :archived"; //it will have the value of $archived
    }
    //Don't use select *, it's unsafe, because if confidential data ends
    //up being stored in the table, then it will be
    $sql = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM people WHERE 1 = 1 ${$archivedCriteria} ORDER BY addedAt DESC";
    //execute $sql, return an associative array
}
```

## Get request

When you load the page, just generate your HTML the way you did.

## Post request

You should receive `$_POST["archived"]` and call `getValues` passing that value. Your output should be `json_encode`d.

## Archive/Restore

These should be POST requests, where the id of the entity to be archived/restored should be passed as well as the action type. This request should perform the update.

## Client-side rendering

It would make sense to create a `function` on client-side for POST requests so that the server would only care about the structure in the case of GET requests. The function would look like this:

```
function displayItem(item) {
    return `
        Some HTML code where ${item['lName']} and other stuff is displayed
    `;
}
```

and the plural:

```
function displayItems(items) {
    let output = [];
    for (let item of items) output.push(displayItem[item]);
    return output;
}
```

So, whenever you do a POST request and receive some JSON that you intend to display, just call `displayItems` to generate the structure.

## Changing the structure of the table

You will need to find the element of the `tbody` and replace its `innerHTML` to the value that you get based on `displayItems`.

## Flow1

- you load the page
- GET request is sent to the server
- server generates HTML and sends that as response
- client-side displays that

## Flow2

- you change the view to see only archived/restored items
- a POST request is sent to the server
- the server calls `getValues` accordingly
- response is returned as JSON
- client-side calls displayItems, passing the response
- and replaces the `innerHTML` of the `tbody` to the response

## Flow3

- you archive/restore an item
- a POST request is being sent to the server
- the server performs the update
- server responds with success
- client-side determines what kind of view should be displayed
- from now on, see Flow2